# Twitter Bootstrap Collapse does nothing

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get collapse to work using the example provided on twitter bootstrap's website. When I try out this code, clicking the link to collapse the content does nothing.
Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>

    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
                Collapsible Group Item #1
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                Anim pariatur cliche...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
                Collapsible Group Item #2
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                Anim pariatur cliche...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the console; any errors?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Bootstrap's JavaScript library relies on jQuery. You need to include that before `bootstrap.js`, eg

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

See the note here - http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/getting-started.html#file-structure

> Please note that all JavaScript plugins require jQuery to be included.

---

Or the modern equivalent ~ http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#jquery-required

> #### jQuery required
>
> Please note that **all JavaScript plugins require jQuery** to be included, as shown in the [starter template](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template). [Consult our `bower.json`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/bower.json) to see which versions of jQuery are supported.