# ajax link breaks jquery on next page load

Tags: jquery, yii

I'm using Yii Booster v2.0.0 (bootstrap) and am having difficulty tracking down a problem that causes jquery to break on `jQuery('#yii_bootstrap_collapse_0').collapse({'parent':false,'toggle':false});`

It throws:

`TypeError: jQuery(...).collapse is not a function`

This is the ajax post that will break on the above line:

`echo CHtml::ajaxLink('test me',  array('post/test'),array(
    'type' => 'POST',
    'success' => "function(data){ console.log(data)}",`

I am able to verify a correct response from the controller

`public function actionTest() {
        echo 'success';
    }`

If I refresh the page approximately 10 or more seconds later, the error goes away! Within that time frame, it seems that not all of the JS is being loaded before the view.

I've deleted the assets folder and tested the link on multiple pages on my site with all the same symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify an ID in htmlOptions of your element, so it won't get another name if a new element is added before this, in DOM and then do what you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

check your console for receive bootstrap.js and jquery.js from server.
if you don't receive, you must register them with registerScript or other ways.
[Twitter Bootstrap Collapse not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179344/twitter-bootstrap-collapse-not-working)