# Bootstrap Modal does not load

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Modal will not auto load when page is loading. I am wondering what I am doing wrong or if I am missing something. Another issue I am having is I am not able to center the button, is there a way to do that with Bootstrap. Other then that, I was able to make it work with a button. Thank you for all your help, I am learning so much.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>YesICan</title>
<meta name="description" content="Hello World">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

 </head>

 <body>

<header>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <h3>Modals in Bootstrap</h3>
        </div> 
    </div> 
</header>

<div class="container">
<!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-1">Activate the button</button>-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                 <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title" style="text-align:center">Safety Warning</h3>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">       
                     <p style="text-align:center"> Your computer use can be monitored by others! Consider using a public computer or a friend's computer. Please view more computer safety tips or escape to Google. Then more computer safety tips linked to a page with details about browser history, cache, search history, etc. and escape to Google linked to Google.</p>
                     <p style="text-align:center"> To learn more how to computer safety, click the following link: <br><a href="#">Safety Tips</a></br></p>
                     <!--Wording can be better just for the meantime-->
                    <p style="text-align:center"> If you are not safe, click the following link: <br><a href="http://www.google.com">Get Me Out of Here!</a></br></p>  
                 </div>

                 <div class="modal-footer">
                    <p class="text-center"><a href="" class="btn btn-default" class="btn pull-middle" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a></p>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <hr>

        <p>
            <small><a href="http://facebook.com/askorama">Like me</a> On facebook</small></p>
        <p> <small><a href="http://twitter.com/wiredwiki">Ask whatever </a> On Twitter</small></p>
        <p> <small><a href="http://youtube.com/wiredwiki">Subscribe me</a> On Youtube</small>

        </p>
    </div> <!-- end container -->
</footer>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$( "#modal-1" ).modal('show ');
});
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Have you included jquery and bootstrap js files?

Comment: Include the required scripts http://plnkr.co/edit/Znc0hw?p=preview

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap Collapse not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179344/twitter-bootstrap-collapse-not-working)

Comment: As to your second question, wrap the button in a centred container, eg `<p class="text-center"><button ...>...</button></p>`

Comment: yes I have included them but I what I mean is like when the page is loading, I would like this to pop up

Comment: Also thank you Phil, that did it for the buton

Comment: Bootstrap seems to have a problem with the hyphenated ID `modal-1`. It works fine over here with `myModal` ~ http://www.bootply.com/cAuMlklBgK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be for ordering of js files. Try following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>YesICan</title>
<meta name="description" content="Hello World">

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
$('#myModal').modal('show');
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<header>
 <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <h3>Modals in Bootstrap</h3>
    </div> 
</div> 
 </header>

 <div class="container">
 <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-    target="#modal-1">Activate the button</button>-->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title" style="text-align:center">Safety Warning</h3>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body">       
                 <p style="text-align:center"> Your computer use can be monitored by others! Consider using a public computer or a friend's computer. Please view more computer safety tips or escape to Google. Then more computer safety tips linked to a page with details about browser history, cache, search history, etc. and escape to Google linked to Google.</p>
                 <p style="text-align:center"> To learn more how to computer safety, click the following link: <br><a href="#">Safety Tips</a></br></p>
                 <!--Wording can be better just for the meantime-->
                <p style="text-align:center"> If you are not safe, click the following link: <br><a href="http://www.google.com">Get Me Out of Here!</a></br></p>  
             </div>

             <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="" class="btn btn-default" class="btn pull-middle" data-dismiss="modal" class="pagination-centered">Close</a>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>


<footer>
<div class="container">
    <hr>

    <p>
        <small><a href="http://facebook.com/askorama">Like me</a> On facebook</small></p>
    <p> <small><a href="http://twitter.com/wiredwiki">Ask whatever </a> On Twitter</small></p>
    <p> <small><a href="http://youtube.com/wiredwiki">Subscribe me</a> On Youtube</small>

    </p>
</div> <!-- end container -->
</footer>
```

Comment: But wont it be best though for the script files to be in the bottom so the site can load faster? That is why I did that

Comment: @RobertoFlores in that case, you need to move your `$(window).load...` script to the bottom, **underneath** the jQuery script. You can't use `$` before it is defined

Comment: @Phil I did what you recommended but nothing happened. Is there something I am doing wrong. This is what I added in the end:  '<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $( "#myModal ).modal('show ');
   });
</script>'

Comment: @RobertoFlores Looks like you're missing a `"` after `#myModal`. If your code has changed, update your question (and get the code indenting right this time so we don't all think you left out the JavaScript files)

Comment: My apologize and I will update my code right how. And yes I was missing a " but it still didnt do anything. I will post the new version in a bit

Answer (score 0):

As advised to you, do include the bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js files; this is **very important**.

To center the button, you can use `text--align:center` on the parent of the button or `margin:0 auto` on the element itself, depending on whether you're using a inline or block element as the button.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/q3k6h3jL/) a fiddle that shows how the bootstrap modal works.

Remember if you want your modal to show on page load, add the following initialization script:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

If you want it to hide though:

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

### Edit

The problem in your code is you have a unnecessary space i.e.

```
$( "#modal-1" ).modal('show '); // notice how there is a space in 'show '
```

remove the space and it should work just fine.

Comment: It doesn't work. I do not know why the script you provided is not working

Comment: @RobertoFlores , can you paste all your code in this http://chopapp.com/ , save it and paste the link either in your question or as a comment !

Comment: http://chopapp.com/#w03prnys this is all the code. It is the same as the code above

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you Alexander, Phil and everyone who helped out. I learned a lot. Thank you all

Comment: @RobertoFlores , no probs , consider accepting an answer :)